# How to refresh a filter onEdit() in Google sheets?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a sheet where I fill data with Hlookups depending on the values I choose in dropdowns.

I want to filter (hide) the rows that have a NULL or blank value in column 3 each time I change the values in the dropdowns (which changes the whole dataset).

If I create a normal filter, it doesn't refresh when the data changes.

```
var PARAMETER_ROW_NUMBER = 5; //The parameters goes from Row 1 to this Row
var PARAMETER_COLUMN_NUMBER = 2; //The column where the dropdowns with the parameters for the VLOOKUPs are


function onEdit() 
{
  var thisSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  if( thisSheet.getName() == "By Place" ) 
  {
    var cell = thisSheet.getActiveCell();
    var cellRow = cell.getRow();
    var cellColumn = cell.getColumn();
    if( cellColumn == PARAMETER_COLUMN_NUMBER && cellRow <= PARAMETER_ROW_NUMBER)
    {
      setFilter(); // Execute the filter to clean null rows each time I change the values in the dropdowns
      var rowDiff = PARAMETER_ROW_NUMBER - cellRow;
      cell.offset( 1, 0, rowDiff).setValue(''); // As the parameters are dependent dropdowns, I clear the dropdowns if one changes
    }
    
  }
}

function setFilter() 
{
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var rang = ss.getDataRange();
  var filtercriteria = SpreadsheetApp.newFilterCriteria().setHiddenValues([' ','']).build();
  var filter = rang.getFilter() || rang.createFilter();
  filter.setColumnFilterCriteria(3, filtercriteria); // I want to hide the rows which has a null or blank in column 3
}
```

The setFilter() function doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

The array you're using to set the hidden values is not correct, try your code like this:

```
function setFilter() 
{
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var rang = ss.getDataRange();
  var filterCriteria = SpreadsheetApp
                         .newFilterCriteria()
                         .setHiddenValues(['NULL', ''])
                         .build();
  var filter = rang.getFilter() || rang.createFilter();
  filter.setColumnFilterCriteria(3, filterCriteria);
}
```

Also, if you want to see the logs from your `onEdit` executions, you can check them on your Apps Script file by clicking in ***View*** -    > ***Executions***, there you will be able to see the errors you are getting.

### Docs

I used these docs to help you:

- [setColumnFilterCriteria(columnPosition, filterCriteria)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/filter#setcolumnfiltercriteriacolumnposition,-filtercriteria).
- [Class FilterCriteriaBuilder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/filter-criteria-builder#build).